# Asp. NET MVC 4.5 - How to Unit Test Actions?

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-4

In Asp.net  MVC 4.5 , using `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting`.

is there a way to really  unit test an `ActionResult`? All documentation I have seen only tests the view name!

```
Assert.AreEqual("Action Method", result.ViewName);
```

Well, I want to have a really test. How can I test the response of the controller-action ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given something basic along the lines of:

```
    public ActionResult Display(string productCode)
    {
        var model = new ProductModel(productCode);

        if (model.NotFound)
        {
             return this.RedirectToRoute("NotFound");
        }

        return this.View("Product", model);
    }
```

Instead of something that asserts like `Assert.AreEqual("Action Method", result.ViewName);` (which can be a valid test.

You have many options including...

**Looking at the model type**

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Display_WhenPassedValidProductCode_CreatesModel()
    {
        using (var controller = this.CreateController())
        {
            // Arrange Mocks on controller, e.g. a Service or Repository

            // Act
            var result = controller.Display(string.Empty) as ViewResult;
            var model = (ProductModel)result.Model;
            Assert.IsInstanceOfType(model, typeof(ProductModel));
        }
    }
```

**Looking at the model population process**

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Display_WhenPassedValidProductCode_PopulatesModel()
    {
        using (var controller = this.CreateController())
        {
            const string ProductCode = "123465";
            // Arrange Mocks on controller, e.g. a Service or Repository

            // Act
            var result = controller.Display(ProductCode) as ViewResult;
            var model = (ProductModel)result.Model;
            Assert.AreEqual(ProductCode, model.ProductCode);
        }
    }
```

**Looking at the type of action result**

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Display_WhenNotFound_Redirects()
    {
        using (var controller = this.CreateController())
        {
            const string ProductCode = "789000";
            // Arrange Mocks on controller, e.g. a Service or Repository

            // Act
            var result = controller.Display(ProductCode) as RedirectToRouteResult;
            Assert.IsNotNull(result); // An "as" cast will be null if the type does not match
        }
    }
```

Basically you can test pretty much anything, pick an example on your code base and try and test it. If you get stuck construct a decent question and post it here.

Comment: Thanks, using NUNIT I cant have the HTML Body as result, with that I can test the content of the body. Using MS Tools I have see I require another project to run aside and testing it